# what is the meaning of debug in web.xml

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, struts

Below i have mentioned a link in which they discussed about the debug level in web.xml

http://dev.anyframejava.org/docs.en/anyframe/plugin/optional/struts/1.0.1/reference/html/ch02.html

```
<init-param>
<param-name>debug</param-name>
<param-value>2</param-value>
</init-param>
```

please I am not getting the proper meaning of the debug as well as their level which they are talking about from 0-6 like for example when i will pass the value 2 int the `<param-value>` what kind of information i will get or if it is 0 or 1 or 6 what i will get

Comment: Why are you using struts 1.0.1? Struts 1.3.x itself is completely obsolete and not maintained anymore. So 1.0.1 shouldn't even be considered.

Comment: @JBNizet: Maybe it's a legacy application?

Comment: @SzymonBiliński: That would explain why it's stuck at 1.3.x. But 1.0.1?

Comment: @JBNizet: It might be a mission critical system, that no one dares to upgrade. My point is - author may not have much choice on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter will be used inside the org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet to estabilish the log level. I am expecting that with 6 you will have the most detailed log level, that is to say TRACE, while with 0 the logging will be OFF, therefore you will not log anything.

With 2 you might have INFO level, but to make sure I would give it a try. You should be able to realize that right away by having a look to the server logs.